# Почему QtDesigner сжимает окно?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Использую `Qt` для написания интерфейса под `Python`.
В `Qt Designer` я получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда запускаю через `Python` вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**gui.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>367</width>
    <height>362</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Парсер для avito.ru</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>251</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>16</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="lineWidth">
    <number>1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Вставьте ссылку на страницу:</string>
   </property>
   <property name="textFormat">
    <enum>Qt::AutoText</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>71</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Начать</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>201</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>18</pointsize>
     <underline>true</underline>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Состояние парсера:</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>11</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Не активен</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from code.main_window_ui import Ui_Form


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

**main_window_ui.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(367, 362)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 221, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 201, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Парсер для avito.ru"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Вставьте ссылку на страницу:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние парсера:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Не активен"))
```

Comment: Из-за абсолютного позиционирования и разницы в шрифтах.
Надо использовать наследников QLayout. Вон там, наверху, серенькие-неактивные кнопочки - выберите родительскую панель для ваших виджетов и эти кнопочки сразу станут цветными, из который выберите QVBoxLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решения очень зависимым от платформы и стиля.

Чтобы узнать, какие стили установлены в системе, просто вызовите QStyleFactory.keys().

```
print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())
```

Обратите внимание, что не все стили доступны для каждой системы.
Обычно доступны `Fusion` и `Windows` что означает,
что если вы попытаетесь получить доступ к стилю `Oxygen`, а он не установлен,
вместо него будет использован запасной стиль.

То что вы предоставили, у меня выглядит по другому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте установить `Fusion`

```
...
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())
    app.setStyle('Fusion')                                # +++ Fusion
    
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
...
```

вот что уменя получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

я согласен с комментарием @AlexanderChernin, старайтесь свегда использовать `QLayoutы`.
я отметил ту кнопочку, о которой говорится в комментарии.
Или нажмите на свободном месте правой кнопкой мышки и 1, 2, 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на конец  ваш `.ui` может выглядеть так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>367</width>
    <height>362</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Парсер для avito.ru</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="4" column="0">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="1">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="1">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Начать</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="2">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0" colspan="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>18</pointsize>
       <underline>true</underline>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Состояние парсера:</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Не активен</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0" colspan="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>16</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="lineWidth">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Вставьте ссылку на страницу:</string>
     </property>
     <property name="textFormat">
      <enum>Qt::AutoText</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="0" colspan="3">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```